# Giving two template class as arguments, choose the return template class using a hierarchy order

Tags: c++, templates, return-value, hierarchy

I have a class Matrix defined as `template<class T, int m_rows, int m_cols = m_rows> class Matrix` and an overloaded operator of the type `template <class V, int m_cols2> Matrix operator * (const Matrix<V,m_cols,m_cols2>& other)`. The idea is that, for example, if T is a complex and V is a double, the returning matrix should be of the type V (complex). How do I accomplish that in the code?

As of now I have

```
    template <class V, int m_cols2>
    Matrix operator * (const Matrix<V,m_cols,m_cols2>& other) const {
        Matrix<T,m_rows,other.m_cols> res;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; ++i) {
            for (int k = 0; k < other.m_rows; ++k) {
                res[i][k] = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < m_cols; ++j) {
                    res[i][k] += m_matrix[i][j]*other[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

But this automatically sets the matrix "res" to the type T.
How can I tell that it should decide the type of res depending on the type hierarchy? For example
complex > double > integer?

Thanks for your answers :)

I have no idea what to try:)

Comment: "real" is not a type. Floating point numbers are very different from real numbers in maths. Do you mean `double > float` ? Or just `double` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai yeah, got confused (I am a physicist :) )Modifying to double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could produce a matrix of a "common type":

```cpp
// note: it's best not to call template parameters "m_something", because
//       it creates confusion with data members of the class.
template <class OtherT, int OtherCols>
auto operator * (const Matrix<OtherT, Cols, OtherCols>& other) const
  -> Matrix<std::common_type_t<T, OtherT>, Rows, OtherCols>> // trailing return type
{
    // Avoid copying and pasing the return type with decltype.
    // We could also use a deduced return type (just auto, no trailing -> ...),
    // however, this wouldn't be SFINAE-friendly, i.e.: operator* gets
    // instantiated even if there is no common type.
    decltype(*this * other) result;

    for // ...

    return result;
}
```

If your `complex` class is [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), you can just use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) like in the above example. Otherwise you may have to specialize `std:common_type<Complex, ...>` for your type to make it work.

This works because a `double` is implicitly convertible to a `std::complex<double>`, but not the other way around. It also works for `int` and `double`, i.e.

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, std::common_type_t<int, double>>); // passes
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try (never heard about `std::common_type`, hope I'll manage! (No, the complex type is a class I created)

Comment: @Alessandro as long as there is an implicit conversion from `double` to your `Complex` type, it should work, just like with `std::complex`. If not, you can still write a specialization of `std::common_type` for your type.

Comment: Yeah I have an implicit conversion and your solution worked! Thanks:)
PS: yeah the m_ somthing thing is because the class was not a template before and I didn't want to be bothered to rewrite the code